# How to select only the first element after class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu. I want it to be dynamic so I can only tell a `li` (in the `nav`) that it is a dropdown and then give it a list afterwards that is dropdown content. The problem is that when you click on a link with the `.dropdown` class it shows all elements with the `.dropdown-content` class. Any idea of a smart selector that would work here?

My HTML:

```
    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Gallery</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a  href="#">Photos on me</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Photos of me</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Photos with me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Blog</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a  href="#">Photos on me</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Photos of me</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Photos with me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

My js:

```
var main = function() {
    $('.dropdown').click(function(){
        $('.dropdown + .dropdown-content').toggle(200);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the element on which click event has happened, and from that find the siblings class that you are looking for.

```
$('.dropdown').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.dropdown-content').toggle(200);
});
```

OR

```
$('.dropdown').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle(200);
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xs7kpnv/)

Answer (score 0):

Just include `data` and `id` to your code. This will resolve your problem.

JS Bin on jsbin.com

```js
(function() {
    $('.dropdown').click(function(e){
        var id = $(this).data('toggle');
        $('#' + id).toggle();
    });
}());
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#" data-toggle="first">Gallery</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content" id="first">
            <li><a  href="#">Photos on me</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Photos of me</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Photos with me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="dropdown" href="#" data-toggle="second">Blog</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content" id="second">
            <li><a  href="#">Photos on me</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Photos of me</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Photos with me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```